# self.view addSubview:(UIView *)logInHome];

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Below is the code i'm using but for some reason it does not take me to the next segue of the app i'm creating. So basically if the wrong password is enter you get an alert stating wrong password but if you eneter the correct password it should then allow you to proceed on to the next segue. I'm fairly new to this. Can anyone help i'm sure i'm missing something in the code or i'm not linking something correctly. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Using xcode 4.6

```
- (IBAction)enterPassword
{
    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1234"];

    if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
        [self.view addSubview:(UIView *)logInHome];

    }
    else {
        // Password is incorrect
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect Password" message:@"Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

@end

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard?

Comment: yes i am using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the wrong track. You should read about the methods `performSegueWithIdentifier` and `prepareForSegue`.

In your button click action check username and password if it is ok call `performSegueWithIdentifier` with the id for the next view else display your alert message.

In `prepareForSegue` you can pass in username and password as parameters for your next view.

You have to setup your views in storyboard.